# open PDF as book in browser

Tags: html, pdf, pdfviewer

I have client where requirement is open PDF in book format in browser. If I scroll to left, it should show effect like book.

Is there any library available for this?

Also it should have zoom and search functionality.

I tried googling, but nothing worked.

Comment: Have you checkd http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ ?

Comment: @Satindersingh : after looking at [this](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) link, I see pages are below each other... I told clearly in question, I want it as book... horizontal scrolling only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the link that is what I was looking for.

```
http://en.calameo.com/
```

You can see demo at http://kuwait.luluhypermarket.com/eid-mubarak-yy553.html

Answer (score 2):

You can try like using Google Docs embedded PDF viewer, just need to set your pdf url

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//intl/en/landing/conversion/conversionsfordummies.pdf&embedded=true" 
style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/32Vhm/)**

Thought it not properly book like laytout, but there is vertical/horizontal both navigation available

Comment: I cannot scroll if I drag the page...